# @RequestBody in Spring Restful Web API not accepting request from client where request is JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

@RequestBody not accepting the request from the client. Kindly help me to solve this

For testing, I am sending JSON data from postman in raw(application/JSON) to my controller in the below format

Error in postman: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

But I guess this is the correct format of JSON. Please correct me if am wrong

```
{
"flight_details": [
{
  "flight_from": "Bangalore",
  "flight_to": "Hyderabad"
},
{
  "flight_from": "Delhi",
  "flight_to": "Pune"
}]
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="addFlightDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public void addOfferTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response,@RequestBody RequirementBean requirementbean){

    System.out.println("flightdetails:"+requirementbean.getFlight_details());

}
```

My Bean class:

```
public class RequirementBean {

  private String flight_details;
 //Getters and Setters
}
```

If I am sending the same request in the below format I am able to receive request

```
{"flight_details":"Bangalore"}
```

But my desired format is the one which mentioned above.

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: `{"flight_details":"Bangalore"}` maps onto `String flight_details;` but in your first code you are passing an array with `flight_from` and `flight_to` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this might works for you...

```
@RequestMapping(value="addFlightDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public void addOfferTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response,@RequestBody String json){

  JSONObject mainObject=new JSONObject(json);
  JSONObject flightdetails=mainObject.getJSONObject("flight_details");
  String flight_from=flightdetails.getString("flight_from");
  String flight_from=flightdetails.getString("flight_from");
  System.out.println(flight_from);
  System.out.println(flight_to);

 }
```

let me know any issues...

Answer (score 0):

You send a json **array** to **controller**. you need to a list to get this array. It could be like this.

```
 public class FlightDetails{

    private String flight_from;
    private String flight_to;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

---

```
   public class RequirementBean {

    private List<FlightDetails> flight_details;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a JSON array to String which is incorrect. You can do it in two ways
1. Create a bean FlightDetails with fields from and to. In this case your controller becomes

```
@RequestMapping(value="addFlightDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public void addOfferTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response,@RequestBody FlightDetails[] requirementbean){ }
```

2. Use RequirementBean which contains array or list of FlightDetail beans.

   public class RequirementBean {
       private List flight_details;
       //Getters and Setters
   }

Answer (score 0):

Change your RequirementBean code as below

```
public class RequirementBean {

  private List<FlightDetail> flight_details;
 //Getters and Setters
}

public class FlightDetail {
  private String flight_from;
  private String flight_to;
 //Getters and Setters  
}
```

Comment: Have tried this way but doesnt worked for me. Thanks @Gnanasekaran

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="addFlightDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void addFlightDetails(@RequestBody String data,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session,OutputStream outp) {


        DBObject  dBObject = new BasicDBObject();
        String message = "";        
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new StringReader(data));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
```